# Spring Rest with shiro

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, shiro

I am building two separate project , Rest services using spring 4.0 and a dynamic website using ZK and Spring .

I want to secure both Rest Services and the Website so user need to be authorized before browsing the website or requesting the Rest Services .

I am wondering if we can have one place for authorization , is this possible and how to share the identity of user between both sites ?

I am thinking of Shiro ?

Any Ideas

BR
Shahbour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Spring Security, it integrates really easily with Spring (as the name would suggest). As far as how to keep user signed in across both apps, there are a few options.  The simplest would probably be to have a central database where user information is stored that both apps can access.  Add Spring Security to both apps.  Web app would require user to authenticate and then any time it calls the REST service it provides current user's username/password. REST service would accept username/password and authenticate the user again. This approach would also work if you ever wanted to use your REST services directly without your Web UI.

Comment: Hello  
 The centralized DB is already there, but my problem with the suggested solution :  

 1) I will have to save the password to use it in each request, which seems risky or not recommended.  
 2) On each Rest request i will have to authenticate all over again.  

I wanted to see if i can share the security manager or what ever is equivalent in spring security for that.

BR
Shahbour

Comment: @Shahbour - 1) what makes you say providing authentication with each request is "risky or not recommended?" 2) there are many approaches to architecting a scalable site/service. what you are doing sounds like separating your app into components. your website will have to maintain state, there is no way around it, otherwise it will forget who the user was from page to page. but your rest service should be stateless, that's what allows it to scale better. it receives a request, completes it, forgets about you.

Comment: Hello when i talked about risky and not recommended i meant saving the password and sending it on each request . As for the rest , it is very logical for rest service .